# How do I pass an ArrayList method to a different method in the same class?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, random

What I am working on is reading in a file and passing it to an ArrayList which I have already done with this:

```
public ArrayList readInPhrase() {

    String fileName = "wholephrase.txt";
    ArrayList<String> wholePhrase = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        //creates fileReader object
        FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);

        //create an instance of BufferedReader
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

        //variable to hold lines in the file
        String line;

        //read file line by line and add to the wholePhrase array
        while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            wholePhrase.add(line);
        }//end of while

        //close buffer reader
        bufferReader.close();

    }//end of try

    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to open file '" +
                fileName + " ' ", "Error", 
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null);
    }//end of file not found catch

    catch(Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error while reading in file '" 
                + fileName + " ' ", "Error", 
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null);
    }//end of read in error

    return wholePhrase;

}//end of readInPhrase
```

The problem that I am now having is that I would like to go through this ArrayList and **randomly select one phrase from it** to eventually append asterisk's
to part of the phrase that is selected. I have tried a variety of different ways to do this.

This is the last attempt that I have tried:

```
public String getPhrase(ArrayList<String> wholePhrase) {

    Random random = new Random();

    //get random phrase
    int index = random.nextInt(wholePhrase.size());
    String phrase = wholePhrase.get(index);

    return phrase;

    }//end of getPhrase
```

Comment: You don't actually explain what's going wrong.

Comment: *"I am not entirely sure where it is that I am getting lost at"* Ditto. We're lost too, since it is unclear what you are trying to do differently than you're already doing. I mean, it can't be as simple as the *"append asterisk's"* parts, because string concatenation it easy.

Comment: Why on earth are you parenthesising the return values? And without a space after `return`. Makes it look like a method call. `return wholePhrase;` and `return phrase;` is how you should do it.

Comment: The problem I am having is in trying to say print out a line to test to make sure that it is working I am getting an error saying that method getPhrase in class HangmanPhrase cannot be applied to given types;
  required: ArrayList<String>
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Then you're calling getPhrase() incorrectly. We need to see the calling code. While you're at it, you should correct the errors that have been noted in the comments and answers.

Comment: added System.out.println(phrase); to getPhrase() and called it in main via HangmanPhrase.getPhrase(); from all of these comments I feel like I have a lot of issues in my code. The only reason I have used () for my return statements is because that how my teacher has us do it

Comment: Edit your question and add the calling code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments on the question, you say you're calling `getPhrase` like this:

```
HangmanPhrase.getPhrase()
```

... which results in the error

```
method getPhrase in class HangmanPhrase cannot be applied to given types;
required: ArrayList<String> found: no arguments reason:
   actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

The reason for this is that `getPhrase` takes an `ArrayList<String>` as an argument:

```
public String getPhrase(ArrayList<String> wholePhrase) {
```

You need to pass an ArrayList to the method `getPhrase` like so:

```
ArrayList<String> myListOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
// do stuff with myListOfStrings
getPhrase(myListOfStrings);
```

Also, since getPhrase is an instance method, not a static method, you cannot call it via `HangmanPhrase.getPhrase`. You need to create an instance of `HangmanPhrase` and call the method from that instance.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. It makes much more sense to me now. I should be able to figure it out now with this

Answer (score 0):

two issues as far as I can see.

1. Return statements in Java follow 'return variable name;' rather than a method type call.
2. You should be getting the array list using your random number subtract one, as indexes start at zero.

Comment: As for #2, `nextInt(int)` return zero-based number.

Answer (score 0):

Then just do `getPhrase(readInPhrase())`. The compiler will call `getPhrase()`, and then evaulate `readInPhrase()` with the stack trace return point at `getPhrase(...)`. This will return the `ArrayList` (which, by the way, needs to be type-parameterized with `<String>`). Then, `getPhrase()` is called with the `ArrayList` as the parameter, and then you get the phrase, and then there was much rejoicing.

Also, `readInPhrase()` needs to be returning an `ArrayList<String>` (in Java 1.5+)